# Load multiple JSON files in pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, local-files

I am new to JavaScript. I have already understood how to create an object from a JSON-file with JSON.Parse() and now I need to load multiple local JSONs into an array. I've been googling my problem for a while, but everything that I found was related to single JSON files.

Is there any way to do this in pure JavaScript without any libraries like jQuery and etc.?

P.S.: There is no need to work with web-server or else, the code is running locally.

Comment: Even jQuery is pure JavaScript, I think you wanted to say plain JS or vanilla JS ( or when talking about browsers native JS API ). And if you are talking about browsers... I think you will need some work in accessing the local files which are supposed to be out of browser sandbox.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To do this, you need to first get the actual files. Then, you should parse them.

```
// we need a function to load files
// done is a "callback" function
// so you call it once you're finished and pass whatever you want
// in this case, we're passing the `responseText` of the XML request
var loadFile = function (filePath, done) {
    var xhr = new XMLHTTPRequest();
    xhr.onload = function () { return done(this.responseText) }
    xhr.open("GET", filePath, true);
    xhr.send();
}
// paths to all of your files
var myFiles = [ "file1", "file2", "file3" ];
// where you want to store the data
var jsonData = [];
// loop through each file
myFiles.forEach(function (file, i) {
    // and call loadFile
    // note how a function is passed as the second parameter
    // that's the callback function
    loadFile(file, function (responseText) {
        // we set jsonData[i] to the parse data since the requests
        // will not necessarily come in order
        // so we can't use JSONdata.push(JSON.parse(responseText));
        // if the order doesn't matter, you can use push
        jsonData[i] = JSON.parse(responseText);
        // or you could choose not to store it in an array.
        // whatever you decide to do with it, it is available as
        // responseText within this scope (unparsed!)
    }
})
```

If you can't make an XML Request, you can also use a file reader object:

```
var loadLocalFile = function (filePath, done) {
    var fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onload = function () { return done(this.result); }
    fr.readAsText(filePath);
}
```

Comment: methinks `XMLHTTPRequest` possible not wirking with local files without webserver

Comment: i not sure with IE also :-)

Comment: @MaxUdalov You can also use the `FileReader` object

Comment: @royhowie is there any way to get filepath recursively? Like I have 10000 files and their paths should be added to myFiles array/

Comment: @MaxUdalov explain. Do you need to generate every file path?

Comment: @royhowie Yes, I need to load files from special folder (like ../JSONs/) and work with them in my code

Comment: @MaxUdalov JavaScript doesn't have access to the file system for security reasons. You can, however, use your shell to generate a list of filenames beforehand. Put this list in a text file, load that file, parse it, then load the files produced listed in that file.

Comment: "Failed to execute 'readAsText' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'.

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this:

```
var file1 = JSON.parse(file1);
var file2 = JSON.parse(file2);
var file3 = JSON.parse(file3);
var myFileArray = [file1, file2, file3];
// Do other stuff
// ....
// Add another file to the array
var file4 = JSON.parse(file4);
myFileArray.push(file4);
```

If you already have an array of un-parsed files you could do this:

```
var myFileArray = [];
for(var i=0; i<unparsedFileArray.length; i++){
    myFileArray.push(JON.parse(unparsedFileArray[i]));
}
```

Comment: This does not seem correct, according to MDN, [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) does not support an URI as argument, as your use of `fileX` seems to suggest.

Comment: This answer assumes the files are already loaded. Per the question, it seems that the OP was asking how to load multiple JSON objects into an array.