# In pure JavaScript, how do I load two JSON files and pass them as named variables?

Tags: javascript, json, asynchronous

I have what I'm sure is a classic beginner's error in Javascript - tripping up on asynchronous callbacks. I want to read some JSON files, then parse the contents into a nested hierarchy. So: load the JSON data from each, assign each to an object, then pass the two objects as parameters to a function that combines them.

In Python I can do:

```
with open('data/vpcs.json') as data_file:
  vpc_data = json.load(data_file)
with open('data/subnets.json') as data_file:
  subnet_data = json.load(data_file)
do_stuff(vpc_data, subnet_data)
```

In Javascript, I have a function that makes an XHR request and then gives me a callback to use once the request is fulfilled. That bit works.

The piece I'm working on is a way to call that twice, and wait for the contents of both my files to come back safely before trying to do any logic on the two data objects. Here's:

```
tree = parse('data/vpcs.json', 'data/subnets.json')

function loadJSON(file, callback) {   
  // makes an XHR request using the code sample here which hands the response back as a callback:  
  // https://codepen.io/KryptoniteDove/post/load-json-file-locally-using-pure-javascript 
}

function parse(vpcs, subnets) {
  loadJSON(vpcs, function(response) {
  // Parse JSON string into object
    var vpc_data = JSON.parse(response).Vpcs;
    console.log(vpc_data); // this works
  });
  loadJSON(subnets, function(response) {
    // Parse JSON string into object
    var subnet_data = JSON.parse(response).Subnets;
    console.log(subnet_data); // this works
  });
  toHierarchy(vpc_data, subnet_data);
  // oh no! this doesn't work! 
  // my variables are outside the callback, and still undefined!
}

function toHierarchy(vpcs, subnets) {
// this poor sad function never gets any JSON.
}
```

I should be calling my toHierarchy function inside a callback - that's the mechanism for making sure my variables are fully populated. But I don't understand what proper callback use looks like here - and I know there are lots of 'callback hell' antipatterns I should avoid!

Presumably I can put one callback inside the other, or do something like this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/28690291/3276583 - which loops through waiting for callbacks to finish and pushes the response into an array. But I don't need these files to be loaded in order, just to be able to set them as named keys in the array.

What's a clean way to do this? Can I write a callback that's a named function instead of an anonymous one, and make it generic: give it a file and the name of a variable I want to set its contents to?

---

EDIT:

From @Bradley Bossard's suggestion down thread, I tried:

```
function parse(vpcs, subnets) {
  var vpc_data = null
  var subnet_data = null
  loadJSON(vpcs, function(response) {
    // Parse JSON string into object
    var vpc_data = JSON.parse(response).Vpcs;
    console.log("In the vpc callback, subnets are: " + subnet_data);   
    tree = toHierarchy(vpc_data, subnet_data);
    console.log(tree);
  });
  loadJSON(subnets, function(response) {
    // Parse JSON string into object
    var subnet_data = JSON.parse(response).Subnets;
    console.log("In subnet callback, vpcs are: " + vpc_data);
    tree = toHierarchy(vpc_data, subnet_data);
    console.log(tree);
  });

  tree = toHierarchy(vpc_data, subnet_data);

  function toHierarchy(vpcs, subnets) {
    if (vpcs === null || subnets === null) {
      return "toHierarchy function returns because things are null :("
    }
```

But I don't seem to be able to access the variable from the one callback within the other:

```
   hierarchise.js:38 In the vpc callback, subnets are: null
   hierarchise.js:40 toHierarchy function returns because things are null :(
   hierarchise.js:45 In subnet callback, vpcs are: null
   hierarchise.js:47 toHierarchy function returns because things are null :(
```

Comment: loadJSON is asynchronous, it'll take time for it get the data, but the script doesn't wait till then , so toHierarchy gets called with undefined vpcs and subnets

Comment: Yup, that bit I understand... What I don't know is what the best practices are for checking that both my bits of data have been loaded, then passing them in to the toHierarchy function! Bradley's answer below looks like it's on the right track.

Comment: You need to nest your callbacks! Like your python example, you want to wait until the first file is loaded before you want to start the second request. That way, both your variables will be in the innermost callback's scope.

Comment: @Bergi - so my question was "is nesting callbacks the right/only way to do this?" - with only two files, it's not too awkward a construction, but I find these anonymous functions a bit clunky and hoped I could abstract them away somehow! Your comment puts it in perspective though... this is exactly what Python is doing too :)

Comment: If you want to abstract away these callbacks, promises are the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi) said, promises are the way to go as it allows you to avoid those nested callbacks.

You'll need to adapt your `loadJson` function to return a promise rather than accept a callback function. That way control is returned back to the caller.

```
function loadJson(file) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      request.open('GET', file);
      request.responseType = 'json';
      request.onload = function() {
        if (request.status === 200) {
          resolve(request.response);
        } else {
          reject(Error('Didn\'t load successfully; error code:' + request.statusText));
        }
      };
      request.onerror = function() {
          reject(Error('There was a network error.'));
      };
      request.send();
    });
}
```

Then you can use the `Promise.all` function to wait for all the requests to complete.

```
tree = parse('data/vpcs.json', 'data/subnets.json');

function parse(vpcs, subnets) {
    Promise.all([loadJson(vpcs), loadJson(subnets)]).then(function(responses) {
        // responses contains the parsed JSON objects in the order of requests
        toHierarchy(responses[0], responses[1]);
    }).catch(function(error) {
        // do error processing here if any promise was rejected
    });
}

function toHierarchy(vpcs, subnets) {
    // do the combination here
    console.log(vpcs);
    console.log(subnets);
}
```

Comment: Amazing!! Thank you, this is exactly the kind of control structure I was hoping for, and a really clear example of how to apply it.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I did not run this code.

I think what you want to do is make the call to toHeiracrchy inside each of the loadJSON callback function, then test each argument to verify they are valid.  If not, return as the function will be called again once the other JSON arrives.  B/c loadJSON is asynchronous, you can't guarantee which piece of JSON will arrive first, so you should only proceed once you have checked that both exist.

```
tree = parse('data/vpcs.json', 'data/subnets.json')

function loadJSON(file, callback) {   
  // makes an XHR request using the code sample here which hands the response back as a callback:  
  // https://codepen.io/KryptoniteDove/post/load-json-file-locally-using-pure-javascript 
}

function parse(vpcs, subnets) {
  var vpc_data = null;
  var subnet_data = null;
  loadJSON(vpcs, function(response) {
  // Parse JSON string into object
    vpc_data = JSON.parse(response).Vpcs;
    console.log(vpc_data); // this works
    toHierarchy(vpc_data, subnet_data);
  });
  loadJSON(subnets, function(response) {
    // Parse JSON string into object
    subnet_data = JSON.parse(response).Subnets;
    console.log(subnet_data); // this works
    toHierarchy(vpc_data, subnet_data);
  });

  function toHierarchy(vpcs, subnets) {
    if (vpcs === null || subnets === null) {
      return;
    }
    // execute only when vpcs and subnets have valid data.
  }
}
```

Comment: That sounds like the right strategy, thank you! I will test :)

Comment: ... Hmmm. This doesn't seem to work as-is, I think because my subnet_data and vpc_data variable don't get returned from the scope of the callback anonymous functions. Will investigate further.

Comment: Oh, I see the issue (and have corrected it).  vpc_data and subnet_data were being declared within the scope of the parse function, and therefore not available outside of it.  By declaring toHeirarchy within that same scope, it should work now.

Comment: In theory I like this plan, but in practice there doesn't seem to be a situation where I get both values available at the same time without nesting callbacks like @Bergi says is necessary. (Will edit question to show an example)