# load multi json data

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

```
var address = [ "data/somedata1.json", "data/somedata2.json", "data/somedata3.json", "data/somedata4.json", "data/somedata5.json"];
```

and function to import this file

```
function readData()
{
    var loadFile = function (filePath, done)
    {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", filePath, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
        xhr.onload = function () { return done(this.responseText) }
        xhr.send();
    }
    address.forEach(function (file, i)
        {
            loadFile(file, function (responseText)
            {
            jsonData[i] = JSON.parse(responseText);
            if(i === 4)
            {
                fill(jsonData);
                document.getElementById("el").innerHTML = jsonData[2].title3;
                Dosometing(jsonData[0])
            }
            })
        })

}
```

All JSON files have absolute 150kb. Problem is, sometimes when I run this code on website I get `jsonData[0]` undefinded and sometimes all load success. It means all data are not load properly. What im doing wrong ? There is any chance to write this code better to make sure all files are loaded properly ?

Comment: You generally use `<script>` not `<code>`. May be try `<script>` tags?

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28690096/load-multiple-json-files-in-pure-javascript

Comment: thanks for advice with <script> unfortunately code from your URL looks the same, I read all post but no more solution how to ready JSON in diffrent way

Comment: What means sometimes? Is it the same machine with the same browser and the same file?

Comment: Are the `<code>` tags part of your code?  I assumed it was an attempt to format code for Stack Overflow.

Comment: No, is not ! I tray to Embed JavaScript in stackoverflow

Comment: Okay.  On Stack Overflow, you embed code using indentation (4 spaces), or small code blocks can be delimited by a backtick `\``.

Comment: Sometimes its mean, when I run program on website opera, chrome, firefox 1 of 10 times all JSON not load correct

Answer (score 0):

One issue is that even for small files it is not guaranteed, that the downloads finish in order.
It would be better to keep track of the finished download count with a separate variable:

```
function readData() {
  var loadFile = function(filePath, done) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", filePath, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
    xhr.onload = function() { return done(this.responseText) }
    xhr.send();
  }
  var finishedCount = 0;
  address.forEach(function(file, i) {
    loadFile(file, function(responseText) {
      jsonData[i] = JSON.parse(responseText);
      finishedCount++;
      if(finishedCount === address.length) {
        fill(jsonData[4]);
        document.getElementById("el").innerHTML = jsonData[2].title3;
        Dosometing(jsonData[0])
      }
    });
  })
}
```

Comment: I modify file like this but i don't know is correct <script>  storeData.forEach(function (file, i)
  {
   loadFile(file, function (responseText)
   {
   jsonData[i] = JSON.parse(responseText);
   if(i === 4 && jsonData[0] != undefined)
   {
    fillContent(jsonData);
    document.getElementById("votes-title").innerHTML = jsonData[2].title3;
    createClubsList(jsonData[0])  
   }
   else if(i === 4 && jsonData == undefined)
   {
    readData();
    console.log("error");
   }
   })
  })</script>

Comment: I just included the modified code in my answer, I thought of something like that.